# Not declared in this scope despite the include of correct file

Tags: c++, sdl

I am trying to re-write a portion of lazyfoo.net's tutorial on mouse events just for the practice. I have re-thought my design after someone on this site suggested I do. I have decided to try adding a graphics class and also making sure that members of a class to not inherit from the class they are a member of, which was one of the problems the last time I posted a question. Please be patient with me because I am not a very experienced programmer and I am in the middle of learning SDL2.0.

I am running Windows 10 on a 64-bit Dell laptop and using Code::Blocks 16.01.

I tried googling this problem and I don't think any of the questions I found pertain to my specific problem, so after fixing a bunch of other errors I have finally came to an error that I don't know how to fix.

After trying to compile the following code I get an error message that says "'mSpriteClips' was not declared in this scope" despite the fact that I included CentralClass, which is where mSpriteClips lives, into my cpp file.

Here is the code.

lbutton.cpp

```
#include "lbutton.h"
#include "lButtonSprite.h"
#include "global.h"
#include "graphics.h"
#include "ltexture.h"
#include "central_class.h"

LButton::LButton()
{
    mButtonPosition.x = 0;
    mButtonPosition.y = 0;

    mCurrentSprite = button::MOUSE_OUT;
}

void LButton::setPosition( int x, int y )
{
    mButtonPosition.x = x;
    mButtonPosition.y = y;
}

void LButton::handleEvent(SDL_Event* e)
{
    //If mouse event happened
    if(e->type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION || e->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN || e->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP)
    {
        //Get mouse position
        int x, y;
        SDL_GetMouseState( &x, &y );

        //Check if mouse is in button
        bool inside = true;

        //Mouse is left of the button
        if(x < mButtonPosition.x)
            inside = false;
        //Mouse is right of the button
        else if(x > mButtonPosition.x + global::BUTTON_WIDTH)
            inside = false;
        //Mouse above the button
        else if(y < mButtonPosition.y)
            inside = false;
        //Mouse below the button
        else if(y > mButtonPosition.y + global::BUTTON_HEIGHT)
            inside = false;

        //Mouse is outside button
        if(!inside)
            mCurrentSprite = button::MOUSE_OUT;
    }
    //Mouse is inside button
    else
    {
        //Set mouse over sprite
        switch(e->type)
        {
        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            mCurrentSprite = button::MOUSE_OVER_MOTION;
            break;

        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mCurrentSprite = button::MOUSE_DOWN;
            break;

        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mCurrentSprite = button::MOUSE_UP;
            break;
        }
    }
}
void LButton::render(Graphics &graphics)
{
    //Show current button sprite
    mButtonSpriteSheet->render(mButtonPosition.x, mButtonPosition.y, graphics, &mSpriteClips[mCurrentSprite]);
}
```

and the file that has the member that the compiler says is not declared.

```
#ifndef CENTRAL_CLASS_H_INCLUDED
#define CENTRAL_CLASS_H_INCLUDED

#include <SDL.h>
#include "lButtonSprite.h"
#include "global.h"
#include "graphics.h"

class LButton;

class CentralClass : public Graphics
{
    // Button objects
    LButton *mButtons[global::TOTAL_BUTTONS];

    // Mouse button sprite rectangles
    SDL_Rect mSpriteClips[button::TOTAL];

public:
    // Call all functions
    CentralClass();

    // Starts up SDL and creates window
    bool init();

    // Loads media
    //bool loadMedia();

    // Main part of the program
    void mainLoop();

    // Frees media and shuts down SDL
    void close();

    // Clean up
    ~CentralClass();
};

#endif // CENTRAL_CLASS_H_INCLUDED
```

Any help is appreciated. I wish these error messages actually told you what the problem was. That would make coding much more enjoyable.

Comment: I don't see the second file included "central_class.h".

Answer (score 4):

> I get an error message that says "'mSpriteClips' was not declared in
>   this scope" despite the fact that I included CentralClass, which is
>   where mSpriteClips lives,

No, it does not. That header file does not declare an object called "mSpriteClips". It does declare a class that happens to have a member of that name:

```
class CentralClass : public Graphics
{
      // ...

    SDL_Rect mSpriteClips[button::TOTAL];
```

Details matter. `mSpriteClips` is not a global object, it's a member of a class. Your error message is apparently coming from here:

```
void LButton::render(Graphics &graphics)
{
    mButtonSpriteSheet->render(mButtonPosition.x, mButtonPosition.y, graphics, &mSpriteClips[mCurrentSprite]);
}
```

This a method called `render()` in a class called `LButton`, which is, obviously, not `CentralClass`; hence having a member of a class referring to a member of some completely unrelated class is not likely to succeed.

It is not clear what is the intent of this chunk of code. Even if `render()` can find an instance of the `CentralClass` class, somewhere, it would not accomplish anything, since `mSpriteClips` is a private class member, and `LButton` will not have access to this private class member anyway.

But, this does answer the question of why you are getting your compilation error.

Comment: mButtonSpriteSheet is actually a member of my graphics class and it is also of type LTexture. The intention is to render a button to a specific position. Forgive me if this sounds dumb but now that we know what the problem is

Comment: Excuse the above comment. I accidentally posted it before it was finished. As I was saying; now that we know what the problem is can you tell me what the solution is because I am at a total loss here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The only one who can figure out the solution would be you, since only you have the full source code, and knows what it is supposed to do. The shown code makes references to various classes and objects that are not shown, and its overall purpose is unclear. I hav eno idea where the code in question should find that "mSpriteClips" from, and it doesn't even sound like it should be even referencing it, since, as I explained, it's an inaccessible private member of an unrelated class. It's likely that the code in question should be using some other array, but which array only you would know.

Comment: @N.Trujito Instead of asking "How do I fix this error?" you should be asking "how do I do <whatever you're trying to do>?". Because for design problems like this, the answer to "how do I fix this error?" is always "do it differently so you don't get the error".